# Sum of Gamma function

Tags: summation, gamma-function

$$ \sum_{t=1}^{n}{\frac{\Gamma(t)}{\Gamma(a+t)}} $$
and the result of wolframalpha is
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvEBS.png)

and I don't know the detail process about it

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\Gamma ( r)}{\Gamma ( a+r)} =\frac{1}{a-1} \cdotp \frac{( a-1) \Gamma ( r)}{\Gamma ( a+r)}\\
=\frac{1}{a-1} \cdotp \frac{( a-1) \cdotp r!}{( a+r-1) !}
\end{gather*}
Again,
\begin{gather*}
\frac{r!}{( a+r-1) !} -\frac{( r+1) !}{( a+r) !} =\frac{r!}{( a+r-1) !}\left( 1-\frac{r+1}{a+r}\right) =\frac{r!}{( a+r-1) !} \cdotp \frac{a-1}{( a+r)}\\
=\frac{r!\cdotp ( a-1)}{( a+r) !}
\end{gather*}
Can you now complete the prof using the above?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!